# Android APK Expansion File questions

Tags: java, android, apk, expansion

I figured since my app is 114 megs I should use an expansion apk.

If I throw all these vids into the raw folder of my project it reaches that size.

With an expansion APK could I get it to download all those videos and throw it into the raw folder?

Answer (score 1):

Create a secondary Zip file and use it to store the video files without any additional compression (using zip -0 from the command line).  There is a library provided (apkx_zip_file) that will allow you to get an asset file descriptor from the Zip file.  From this, you can pass the offset and length into the MediaPlayer.  If you need to use the VideoView, you can also set up your own content provider using APEZProvider, which is also in the library.